# What is discarding these unused declarations in my Typescript project?

Tags: typescript, vite

I have a Typescript class on a Vite project that has some functions and exposes them to a script that is executed on an `eval()` call.

```js
moveUp() { /*...*/ }
moveDown() { /*...*/ }
moveRight() { /*...*/ }
moveLeft() { /*...*/ }

execute(code: string) {
    const moveUp = this.moveUp.bind(this)
    const moveDown = this.moveDown.bind(this)
    const moveLeft = this.moveLeft.bind(this)
    const moveRight = this.moveRight.bind(this)    
    eval(code)
}
```

On a development server this works, but after building the project the moveX declarations seems to be stripped and trying to call them gives an error saying that the function is undefined.

I need to create a bogus iteration over all of them and print them for this to work on a built project.

```
const functions = [moveUp, moveDown, moveLeft, moveRight]
functions.forEach(i => console.log(i)) // needed to keep the declaration
```

My question is, what is stripping these declarations and how to prevent this?

Comment: Can you add more details like the complete code of 2 files (imports etc). While tree shaking removes seemingly unused code, this should not have done like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **vite**, I would recommend you to look into it's configuration options for an answer to your problem. As far as I know, **vite** uses **esbilld** as default [code minifier](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-minify). In it's turn, **esbuild** performs [tree-shaking](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#tree-shaking) (aka dead code elimination), and it looks pretty much as what you are looking for.